# Are fixpoints of monotone functions monotone?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, recursion, fixed-points

**Edited!**
I work with power sets and functions on power sets. These are by definition partially ordered by set inclusion. Therefore I have limited the used definitions to those (typically, these definitions are much more general).

**Def.** A *complete lattice* is a partially ordered set $(\wp(A),\subseteq)$ where every subset ($X \subseteq \wp(A)$) has a supremum (join) $\bigcup X \in A$ and an infimum (meet) $\bigcap X \in A$.

**Def.** A function $f\colon \wp(A) \rightarrow \wp(A)$, where $(\wp(A),\subseteq)$ is a partially ordered set, is a *monotone function* if
$X \subseteq Y \Rightarrow f(X) \subseteq f(Y)$ whenever $X,Y \in \wp(A)$.

**Def.** A *fixpoint* of a function $f\colon \wp(A) \rightarrow \wp(A)$ is an element $X \in \wp(A)$ where $X = f(X)$. Let $X\in \wp(A)$, we denote $n$ applications of $f$ to $X$ by $f^n(X)$, eg. $f(f(X)) = f^2(X)$.

**Theorem (Knaster-Tarski).**
Let $(\wp(A),\subseteq)$ be a complete lattice and let $f\colon \wp(A) \rightarrow \wp(A)$ be a monotone function. Then the set of fixed points of $f$ in $\wp(A)$, i.e., $\mathsf{Fix}\, f =\{X \in\wp(A)\mid X = f(X)\}$ is also a complete lattice.

*Question 1:*
Is the following correct?
Since $(\wp(A),\subseteq)$ be a complete lattice then $\wp(A)$ has a supremum $\bigcup \wp(A) \in \wp(A)$. So, because $f$ is monotone and there is no bigger element than $\bigcup \wp(A)$ then $f(\bigcup \wp(A))=\bigcup \wp(A)$.

*Question 2:*
Is the following correct?
Let $X \in \wp(A)$. Because $f$ is monotone then there exists a $k$ such that $f^k(X) \in \mathsf{Fix}\, f$. This seems somehow related to the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

*Question 3:*
We will need an extra definition (can only be introduced if Question 2 is ok).
**Def.** Let $\mathsf{lfp}_f(X)$ denote the fixpoint reached by $f^k(X)$ whenever $X\in \wp(A)$.
Is the following correct and if so, I'm looking for clues to why.
$X \subseteq Y \Rightarrow \mathsf{lfp}_f(X) \subseteq  \mathsf{lfp}_f(Y)$ ?

Comment: What does a fixpoint of $f$ on $A$ mean?

Comment: Apply $f$ repeatedly to $A$. Let $f(f(A))=f

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone and hitted the post button accidently. Let $f^n(A)$ denote $n$ applications of $f$, eg $f^2(A)=f(f(A))$. The fixpoint (and it is the point where $f^n(A)=f^{n+1}(A)$.

Comment: How do you know such $n$ exists for an arbitrary $A \in C$ ?

Comment: To be clearer. I have assumed that $C=(C,\subseteq)$ is a complete lattice.

Comment: @Adayah: I hope the edited version makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: @quasi: I hope the edited version makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes, but is $\wp(A)$ the power set of $A$ or some subfamily if the power set?

Comment: $\wp(A)$ is the power set of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

1. Incorrect. Incidentally, note that $\bigcup \wp(A) = A$. It is indeed the greatest element of $\wp(A)$, but it doesn't mean that $f(A) = A$, because there may be no $B \subseteq A$ such that $f(B) = A$ at all. Consider for example $f(B) = \varnothing$ for all $B \in \wp(A)$.
2. Wrong. Consider a function $f : \wp(\mathbb{N}) \to \wp(\mathbb{N})$ given by $\wp(B) = \{ b+1 : b \in B \}$. It is clearly monotone but the sequence $f^k(\{ 0 \}) = \{ k \}$ doesn't stabilize. Also it's an interesting example to test any other conjecture you might have.
3. Invalidated, but can be partially answered. Suppose $X \subseteq Y$. Then by monotonicity for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we must have that $f^n(X) \subseteq f^n(Y)$, so if both $f^k(X)$ and $f^k(Y)$ stabilize at some point, then there is common $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathsf{lfp}_f(X) = f^n(X)$ and $\mathsf{lfp}_f(Y) = f^n(Y)$, so $\mathsf{lfp}_f(X) \subseteq \mathsf{lfp}_f(Y)$.